# Star domain of the set

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

> $\mathbb{C} $ \ $ \{z=x+iy \in \mathbb{C} | \, {\bf Re}\,z=0 \text{ and } {\bf Im}>0\}$
>
> Is this a star domain and if so what is it centered at?

Any help appreciated

Comment: Yes. Centered at origin.

Answer (score 2):

Let's call $A=\{x+iy\in \mathbb C : Re(z)=0, Im(z)>0\}$. This set consists of the points $\{iy: y>0\}$. It is always useful to draw it.

So your set is basically $\mathbb C\setminus A$, which is all the plane except that half-line (the origin is not in $A$):

[image]

You can see that, intuitively, it is centered at the origin. Now, what's left is: pick a point $(x_0,y_0)\in \mathbb C\setminus A$, find the equation of the segment that goes through $(0,0)$ and $(x_0, y_0)$ and prove there can't be points of $A$ in it.

---

Pick $z_0=(x_0, y_0)\in D=\mathbb C\setminus A$. That means that $z_0$ cannot satisfy $x_0=0$ and $y_0>0$ at the same time. The segment that goes from $(x_0, y_0)$ to $(0,0)$ is the set $$[0,z_0]=\{(tx_0, ty_0), t\in[0,1]\}$$

Now, suppose that for a $t\in[0,1]$ the point $(tx_0, ty_0)$ lies in $A$. Then it must verify the following conditions:
$$(i) \ tx_0=0 \Rightarrow t=0 \text{ or } x_0=0$$
$$(ii) \ ty_0>0 \Rightarrow y_0>0$$
but if $t=0$, then the point is $(0,0)$ which we know is not in $A$. So if a point of the segment lies in $A$, then $z_0$ lies in $A$. But we picked $z_0$ in $D$, so we've arrived to a contradiction. So $[0,z_0]$ must lie in $D$.

Comment: Ive been trying to use the definition of a star domain which is 'A domain $D$ is a star domain with centre $z_0$ if for each point $ w ∈ D$ the entire line segment [$z_0,w$] = ${wt + z_0(1-t) | t ∈ [0,1] }$ lies within $D$' how can i use this with your answer?

Comment: I'll add it to my answer in a moment. At least, I hope you see intuitively that for every point that's not in the red line $A$, the segment that goes from that point to (0,0) is in $\mathbb C\setminus A$. That gives you an idea of a posible centre.

Comment: Hence it is a star domain centered at the origin?

Comment: Or is it not a star domain?

Comment: Yes, it is. If a segment [0,z_0] is not in $D$, then $z_0$ is not in D. So if $z_0$ is in $D$, then $[0,z_0]$ is in D, too.

Comment: Sorry, im still not sure what this star domain is centred at. Can you help me further? is it centered at the origin?

Comment: @user407151 Sure, what do you need?